# Waypoints not existing in overview_path ( google maps API )

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an interface using google maps API. It displays the route that follows waypoints, and all the latitude and longitude coordinates (using overview_path).

The problem is that the array returned by overview_path doesn't contain the waypoints I used to draw the route.

This the function that displays lat/lng and is supposed to check if the current coordinate exists in the array of waypoints.

```js
function getLatLng(point) {
    //alert(k);

    
    var lat = point.lat(),
        lng = point.lng();
    var tmp = msg[k].split(",");
    //  alert(  Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[0]- lat)) )
    if (Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[0] - lat)) < 0.0009 && Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[1] - lng)) < 0.0009) {
        k++;
        return " { \"lat\": " + lat + " ,\"lng\" : " + lng + " ,\"waypoint\" : 1},";
    } else {
        return " { \"lat\": " + lat + " ,\"lng\" : " + lng + " ,\"waypoint\" : 0},";
    }
    
}
```

Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/122/) in jsfiddle.

Any suggestion?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overview_path is simplified (is is an "overview").  If you want all the points, you have to get all of them from the directions response.